# existence of smooth functions with support $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In my real analysis homework, theres a question which begins with

"let $F$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(F)=\{0\}$"

This means that the only $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\langle F,\phi\rangle\neq 0$ are the $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions whose support is $0$, meaning they are zero everywhere except perhaps at $0$? In particular, $F$'s only nonzero values come from the delta function or zero functions?

I'm confused and any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may find reading [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29) useful.

Comment: Please write $\langle F,\phi\rangle\neq 0$ rather than $<F,\phi>\neq 0$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $F$ has support $\{0\}$ if $\langle F,\phi\rangle=0$ for all $\phi$ with support not intersecting $0$. In other words, only functions $\phi$ with support intersecting $0$ may have $\langle F,\phi\rangle\ne0$.

Comment: Perhaps we should stress the point that having $\operatorname{Supp}(F)=\{0\}$ **does not** imply that $\langle F,\phi\rangle\neq 0$ only if $\operatorname{Supp}(\phi)=\{0\}$.